# A limit related to an alternating series

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, special-functions

Show that the limit
$$
\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\bigg(\sum_{k=1}^{2N-1}(-1)^{k+1}\frac{\sin\big(\frac{\pi}{2N}\big)}{\sin\big(\frac{k\pi}{2N}\big)}\bigg) = 2\ln2
$$
holds.

Hint: I think the identity $$\frac{1}{\sin(z\pi)}=\frac1\pi\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n+z}$$ may be of some help.

Comment: Thank you for your question! It is good practice on this site to add a bit of information on the context your question came up in, and to share your own work on it. It's also fine if you state that you're completely lost -- the information is helpful for answerers to gauge their answer on. For more information on asking a good question on this site, see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959/43351).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a thinly disguised version of the sum $1-\frac 12+\frac 13 -\frac 14+\cdots=\log 2$.

Split the sum into three ranges, (1) $1\le k\le N-1$, (2) $N+1\le k\le 2N-1$, and (3) $k=N$.  Throw the third piece away as it vanishes in the limit as $N\to\infty$.  After making the transformation $k\mapsto 2N-k$, (2) becomes identical to (1).  This leaves us with the limit of
$$2\left( \frac{\sin \alpha_N}{\sin \alpha_N}-\frac {\sin \alpha_N}{\sin 2\alpha_N}+\frac {\sin \alpha_N}{\sin 3\alpha_N}-\cdots
\pm \frac{\sin \alpha_N}{\sin (N-1)\alpha_N} \right),
\qquad \alpha_N:=\frac{\pi}{2N}.
$$
The terms in the sum occur in pairs, each positive term paired with a succeeding negative term.  If there is an unpaired term at the end, throw it away as it will vanish in the limit as $N\to\infty$.  Then, subtract the terms in each pair to get
$$
\lim_{N\to\infty} 2\sum_{k \ge 1} b_{N,k}, \quad (*)
$$
where $b_{N,k}$ is zero if $k>\lfloor (N-1)2 \rfloor$ and otherwise
$$b_{N,k}:=\frac{\sin{\alpha_N} (\sin{(2k\alpha_N)} - \sin{((2k-1)\alpha_N)})}{\sin{((2k-1)\alpha_N)} \sin{(2k\alpha_N)}}.
$$
Notice that for each fixed $k$, we have
$$
\lim_{N\to\infty} b_{N,k} = \frac{1}{(2k-1)(2k)}
$$
so
\begin{eqnarray*}
2 \sum_{k\ge 1} \lim_{N\to\infty} b_{N,k}
&=& 2\left(\frac{1}{1\cdot 2} + \frac{1}{3\cdot 4} + \frac{1}{5\cdot 6} +\cdots\right)\\
&=&2 \left(1-\frac 1 2 + \frac 13 -\frac 14+\cdots\right)=2\log 2.
\end{eqnarray*}
Therefore, if the  limit and the sum in $(*)$ could be interchanged, you would have what you want.  Use the dominated convergence theorem to argue that they can be interchanged.